# Google Street View in building worked - now broken

Tags: google-maps, google-street-view

So, i have a problem. I had google maps street view on my site, there was a building panorama (inside), now API shows only street view near this building. Why and how can i fix it?

Here is my code:

```js
        function initialize() {
            var fenway = new google.maps.LatLng(52.4980685,13.2951895);
            var panoramaOptions = {
                zoom: 1,
                panControl:false,
                zoomControl:false,
                mapTypeControl:false,
                scaleControl:false,
                rotateControl:false,
                streetViewControl:false,
                overviewMapControl:false,
                disableDefaultUI: false,
                addressControl: false,
                addressControlOptions: {
                    position: google.maps.ControlPosition.BOTTOM,
                    hide: true
                },
                position: fenway,
                pov: {
                    heading: 0,
                    pitch: 0
                }
            };
            var panorama = new google.maps.StreetViewPanorama(document.getElementById('pano'), panoramaOptions);
            google.maps.setStreetView(panorama);
        }

        google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

Answer (score 0):

This may be a kind of bug(feel free to report it).

I guess you are talking about the place **"Shebell Institut"**.

Let me explain why it's a bug:

Currently

- the ID for this panorama is (at least for me):`ag1bfIf47xUAAAGuxVUjCQ`
- and the location of the panorama(reported by the StreetViewService): `(52.498042,13.29517199999998)`

The location in your code differs a little bit, but when I use the exact location it should show the desired panorama(because it's the nearest)...but it doesn't.

Also when I query the panorama via `StreetViewService.getPanoramaByLocation` another panorama (with another location) will be returned, although the documentation says:
 ***If the radius is less than 50 meters, the nearest panorama will be returned.***
...but when I use the exact location it shouldn't return a panorama with another location.

I don't have a solution, because regarding to the documentation panorama-ID's are only stable within sessions.

But this must not mean that the panorama-ID must change often(I don't know what forces the change of a panorama-ID, but I can't imagine that the ID will be changed randomly).

So let's give it a try and use the panorama-ID(optionally).

1. set the panorama-location(`fenway` in this case) to

   ```
   (52.498042,13.29517199999998)
   ```
2. request the panoramaData based on the ID (`ag1bfIf47xUAAAGuxVUjCQ`)
3. when both locations (`fenway` and the location of the returned panorama) are equal you may assume that it's still the ID of the desired panorama and use this panorama

   ```
       new google.maps.StreetViewService()
         .getPanoramaById('ag1bfIf47xUAAAGuxVUjCQ',
           function(data,status){
             if(google.maps.StreetViewStatus.OK===status 
                  &&
               data.location.latLng.toUrlValue()==fenway.toUrlValue()
               ){
                 panorama.setPano(data.location.pano);
               }
         });
   ```

Demo: [**http://jsfiddle.net/doktormolle/uwqvr5ee/**](http://jsfiddle.net/doktormolle/uwqvr5ee/)

When it's sometimes not the desired panorama you may send a notification to the site-admin so that he may update the pano-ID. 
I know it's not perfect, but it's the only approach I can think of so far(apart from a [custom panorama](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/streetview#CustomStreetView))